# How to create several directories in linux using full character set?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I would like to create several thousand directories on ubuntu per command line.

Using `mkdir {000..999}` does create 1.000 directories name 001, 002 etc.

How do I create directories using the entire character range `[0-9][a-z]`?

The result should look like this

```
001
002
...
00a
00b
...
```

Comment: you could do it in Python using base36. some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181919/python-base-36-encoding

Comment: I just wan to point out that you should be careful using either `{a..Z}` or `{A..z}` as brace expansion, as there are special characters in between.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you'd hit the parameter limit ARG_MAX after the shell expansion.. Better to write a small loop.

Comment: Writing a phyton script seems overkill to me. Is there not an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: @Fiximan: What special do you see in `[` `\ ` `]` `^` `_` `\``?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi only the fact that `{A..z}` is not the same as `{A..Z} {a..z}` which might not be what one would expect when using this the first time.